# IP address returned by MPI_Open_port

Tags: mpi

I want to establish communication between server and client with mpich-3.2, however the `MPI_Open_port` always open port on 127.0.0.1 so that the client cannot connect to server. Are there any solutions to changing the IP address?

Comment: Searching the Internet for `MPICH MPI_Open_port` one arrives at [this page](http://mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Open_port.html) (first result in DuckDuckGo), which documents the use of the `ip_address` info key to specify the IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this solution but it didn't work. I use the code MPI_Info_set(port_info, "ip_address", "192.168.83.228"); to specify the IP address, the return IP address is still 127.0.0.1 @HristoIliev